# How can I make my character jump in java?

Tags: java

I watch thenewboston's tutorials on youtube, so right now I am creating "Bucky's Land." This code currently lets me move my character left, right, up and down. It changes the sides of the player depending on how he is moving. I am a beginner at java and I want to know how to make my character jump. Any help would be appreciated!

```
package javagame;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Play extends BasicGameState{

Animation bucky, movingUp, movingDown, movingLeft, movingRight;
Image worldMap;
boolean quit = false;
int[] duration = {200,200};
float buckyPositionX = 0;
float buckyPositionY = 0;
float shiftX = buckyPositionX + 320;
float shiftY = buckyPositionY + 160;
boolean jumping = false; 
float verticalSpeed = 0.0f;

public Play(int state){
}

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{
   worldMap = new Image("res/world.png");
      Image[] walkUp = {new Image("res/buckysBack.png"), new Image("res/buckysBack.png")}; 
      Image[] walkDown = {new Image("res/buckysFront.png"), new Image("res/buckysFront.png")};
      Image[] walkLeft = {new Image("res/buckysLeft.png"), new Image("res/buckysLeft.png")};
      Image[] walkRight = {new Image("res/buckysRight.png"), new Image("res/buckysRight.png")};

      movingUp = new Animation(walkUp, duration, false);
      movingDown = new Animation(walkDown, duration, false);
      movingLeft = new Animation(walkLeft, duration, false);
      movingRight = new Animation(walkRight, duration, false);
      bucky = movingDown; 
  }

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{
   worldMap.draw(buckyPositionX, buckyPositionY);
   bucky.draw(shiftX, shiftY);
   g.drawString("Buckys X: "+buckyPositionX+"\nBuckys Y: "+buckyPositionY, 400, 20);

   if(quit==true){
         g.drawString("Resume (R)", 250, 100);
         g.drawString("Main Menu (M)", 250, 150);
         g.drawString("Quit Game (Q)", 250, 200);
         if(quit==false){
            g.clear();
         }
    }
 }

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException{
   Input input = gc.getInput();
   if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)){
         bucky = movingUp; //change bucky to up image
         buckyPositionY += delta * .1f; //increase the Y coordinates of bucky (move him up)
         if(buckyPositionY>162){
            buckyPositionY -= delta * .1f; //dont let him keep going up if he reaches the top
         }
      }
      if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)){
         bucky = movingDown;
         buckyPositionY -= delta * .1f;
         if(buckyPositionY<-600){
            buckyPositionY += delta * .1f;
         }
      }
      if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){
         bucky = movingLeft;
         buckyPositionX += delta * .1f;
         if(buckyPositionX>324){
            buckyPositionX -= delta * .1f;
         }
      }
      if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){
         bucky = movingRight;
         buckyPositionX -= delta * .1f;
         if(buckyPositionX<-840){
            buckyPositionX += delta * .1f;
         }
      }
        //when they hit escape
      if(quit==true){
         if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_R)){
            quit = false;
         }
         if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_M)){
            sbg.enterState(0);
            try{
               Thread.sleep(250);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
         if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_Q)){
            System.exit(0);

         }
     }
}

public int getID(){
  return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zoop it looks like OP is in learning phase, so a comment like "what have you tried" won't help in this case.

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11491404/1065197) could help you to get your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I don't understand how to add this code to make it realistic.    "x = xInitial + vInitialX*time;
and
y = yInitial + vInitialY*time - 0.5*g*time*time;
here g is gravitation (simply use 10)."   Can you tell me where in my code I have to put it and what this is? Do I have to declare these at the top as "int" or something else?

Comment: have you been taught basic physics? learn how an object in free fall moves. basically you can calculate the objects altitude if you know the g-force acceleration and starting velocity and position.

Comment: I would say that you should declare them as floats like the rest of the coordinates. (buckyPositionZ)

Comment: also I suggest you go through the code you have and comment it while reading it and make sure you understand what it does and why.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I finally got it. I used an if condition that made my character jump up 100 pixels then fall back on the same spot. @LuiggiMendoza - Thanks a lot for your link. That's what helped me the most!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to a bit of physics for that. the idea is that when somebody presses the space bar for example, you set the velocity of the character to for example 5 up. Each second you substract 1 from it and add it to the character's altitude, until he hits the ground again. You might also want to limit the velocity to (5,-5)

Comment: of course the other option is to set "jumping" state to 5 and then decrement by 1 each second and draw the char as "jumping" when jumping state is bigger than 0.

Comment: Hey I'm a 14-yr old, I'm trying my best- But can you give me a little more help? Like a sample code, or a snippet of code to jumpstart me?

Comment: umm. difficult without actually understanding what kind of a game you are doing. I suggest you google for more tutorials.

Comment: basically you have to have a picture for the char to look like it is jumping. then you need to define when he is jumping, and for how long and then you need to use some key to trigger the jump.